# How to print text in a box of asterisks in an output file?

Tags: python, function, parameters, parameter-passing

**I am working on the following hw question, and am now just trying to fine-tune my code...**

*Write a program that takes in a file that has a message. The message can be any length.*

*Your program will contain two functions. The first should have a function that processes the contents of the file. The second will take the output from the first function and will print the message in a box of asterisks.*

*The input file should just be a single-lined message (see attached input example). The output should take that message, split it between two lines, and center it in the box*

**This is my current code:**

```
import textwrap

def func1():
    infile=open("october.txt", "r")
    'Pull text from file and assign it to process_contents variable'
    process_contents=infile.read()
    return process_contents


def asterisk_box(width, height):
    'Create a box of asterisks and return it as a string'
    box = '*' * width + '\n'
    for i in range(height - 2):
        box += '*' + ' ' * (width-2) + '*\n'
    box += '*' * width
    return box

def asterisk_message(width, height, message):
    'Put a message within the asterisk box'
    assert len(message) <= height  # Make sure there is room for a message
    assert len(message) <= width  # Make sure the box is wide enough
    box = asterisk_box(25,20)
    box = box.splitlines()
    row = height // 2
    box[row] = "*" + message.center(width) + "*"
    box[row] = textwrap.fill(message,4)
    return '\n'.join(box)


def func2():
    outfile=open("october_output.txt", "w")
    print(asterisk_message(30,25, func1()), file=outfile)
    outfile.close()



func2()
```

The code I have will only work with a very small word like "hello"; with any longer message, the 'assert' kicks in and the code won't run. Is there any way to make the box of asterisks automatically expand or compress based on the length of my message? I was trying to use textwrap to compress longer messages to fit into the box, but doing that is leaving me with weird formatting & is messing up the asterisk box, like so:

```
*************************
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
so l
et's
try 
long
er?
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*************************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
width = 30
message = "This is a test"
msg_ary = message.split(' ')
message1 = ' '.join(msg_ary[0: len(msg_ary) // 2]).center(width, ' ')
message2 = ' '.join(msg_ary[len(msg_ary) // 2:]).center(width, ' ')

print('*' * (width + 4))
print(f'* {message1} *')
print(f'* {message2} *')
print('*' * (width + 4))

> **********************************
> *            This is             *
> *             a test             *
> **********************************
```

Since this is homework, some explanation:

**width = 30**:   Just some arbitrary width I chose, just as long as it fits your text.
**msg_ary = ......** : Split the message by words (spaces) to make the break into to not split a word
**messag1 = ...., message2 = ....** : make the array in to a sentence again, note the handy call to "center" at the end : )